# Can I make variable1 > variable2 with strings not numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making Rock Paper Sciessors easy game with easy logic and I wonder if I can compare variable strings not numbers for example rock is > than paper

something like this

```
var rock = rock;
 var paper = paper;
 var result rock > paper;
 if(result){
 alert("rock wins");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you want here.  You certainly could create `rock`/`scissor`/`paper` objects with `valueOf` or `toString` properties that you could then use for comparison, but I don't think that would actually help.

The point of the game is that the comparison is not transitive. <sup>1</sup>.  And JS comparison operations are meant to work on transitive data, so I think this would fall apart

So while there might be some really ugly tricks that could get this working the way you want, they would feel more like language abuse than like reasonable code.

---

<sup>1</sup> *transitivity* is the property of a mathematical relationship like `<` that says that if `a < b` and `b < c` then `a < c`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to compare strings, such as:

```
('a' > 'a')  // false
('a' > 'b')  // false
('b' > 'a')  // true
('bb' > 'b') // true
```

But with "rock", "paper", "scissors", the string values wont give you the desired results for the game to work correctly.

In order to get the desired result, you would have to assign a value to each string.

Something like this:

```
const items = {
    paper: 1,
    rock: 2,
    scissors:3
}

if (items.scissors > items.rock) {
    console.log('Scissors wins!');   
}
```